# How to add Typo3 Extensions to a page?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I googled for quite some time now and i cannot find a solution for such an easy beginner-problem.

I used the Typo3 Extension Builder to build a test-extension in Extbase. Now i want to use this and include it into one of my pages in the page tree structure to actually see if it works. When browsing the folder structure i can clearly see that the Domain model, the Controllers and all the views have properly been generated. But... How can i tell my page to include it and execute it?

I tried things like including the auto generated typescript into the templates of the pages but nothing works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Extension Builder make sure that you added "Frontend plugin" on the left pane. If you'll do it properly you will be able to add this plugin via CE "General Plugin" and then via field "Select plugin"

Comment: Thanks, but how do i "execute" it? What TypoScript do i need for that? I just added it and nothing happens...

Comment: Can't help you sorry, not too much info to guess what's wrong

Comment: You need to include the TypoScript template of your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you struggle on a more general level here.
In order to get the output of your Extension in the Frontend you have to assure the following steps:

1. Set up general Configuration, so that you can see the output of standard content elements in the frontend.
2. Install your extension and include its TypoScript.
3. Make sure you have a Plugin configured in your ext_localconf.php and registered in your ext_tables.php.
4. In the backend, create a new content element and choose "plugin" as its type.
5. Choose your registered plugin and save.
6. You should now see output of your extension in the frontend.